# Bin/Hex/Base64 Confusion

Tags: php, binary, base64, hex

[image]

Sorry if this is simple & possibly even redundant. I'm just a few months into learning.

Currently I'm trying to convert different strings (some binary, some hex) into a safe format to allow for data storage & the ability for server users to choose their own language (english/chinese/etc.) when visiting the site without problems in hex/bin formats.

Is the conversion chart picture correct, or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *different strings (some binary, some hex)* - if something is binary (usually not printable) then it's not a string. hex usually refers to a printable format in which you use two hexadecimal character for one byte value. That's already safe but not efficient. And base64 can be used to encode binary data directly. But what is the real question you have?

Comment: Ah thank you! I'm just trying to get words to go from say English to Chinese(Mandarin) symbols. I've got my own simplified language conversion chart already setup as function, however, when I convert english to chinese symbols it returns unreadable characters. I was wrapping Base64 inside of hex2bin and back again. Once I removed the Base64 everything worked. Again thank you!! Some Reddit post a few days ago suggested Base64 and had me spiralling for a while lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're storing strings, serializing the data to a file will work, even with control characters or weird bytes. There's no weird data loss upon writing to a file. Writing a base64 version of the data to a file is redundant.

Comment: Thank you! I took yours, and jps, suggestion of removing the Base64 conversion and the characters were able to convert successfully!